# Changing UIView in Parse login window unexpectedly moves text fields

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uiimageview, parse-platform

I've successfully integrated the Parse.com login service to my app, but am having trouble changing the logo in the login window (`PFLoginViewController`). Specifically, the logo's view appears to change position after the new logo is set.

> Original 'Parse' logo frame: (159,128,222,68)
>
> New custom logo frame: (60,12,420,68)

The other big problem is that the username and password fields move up ~100 px if I use a different logo. This means that they overlap the new logo, and it all looks quite messy.  Here are the coordinates of the username field in both cases.

> Username field with 'Parse' logo: (60,232,420,44)
>
> Username field with custom logo: (60,116,420,44)

I'm not sure what I'm missing, so any guidance would be terrific. Thanks for reading!

Miscellanea:

- The new logo is 720x300.
- For the logo substitution, I subclassed `PFLoginViewController` using code based on Parse's [login tutorial](https://parse.com/tutorials/login-and-signup-views).

Answer (score 2):

I've found a workable way forward, and though I'm still on the lookout for something better, I wanted to share this solution in the meantime.

Because `PFLoginViewController` appears to a) reset the size and position of the original logo view right before `viewDidAppear`, and b) position the rest of the window elements (e.g., username field) relative to the logo's view, I stopped trying to replace the original logo altogether.

Instead, I added two subviews to the original logo's view: the first is a `UIView` to cover up the original logo (in case your new logo has transparency); the second is a `UIImageView` with the new logo. The code goes in `viewWillAppear` and appears to work fine. (The main downside is that the new logo ends up with the same size and position of the old logo.)

```
// Create a UIView to "cover up" original Parse logo
UIView *blankRect=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,
                                                           0,
                                                           self.logInView.logo.frame.size.width,
                                                           self.logInView.logo.frame.size.height)];
[blankRect setBackgroundColor:self.logInView.backgroundColor];
[self.logInView.logo addSubview:blankRect];

// Add a subview with the new logo to the original logo's view    
UIImageView *newLogo=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"LoginLogoTight.png"]];
[newLogo setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill];
[newLogo setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,self.logInView.logo.frame.size.width,self.logInView.logo.frame.size.height)];
[self.logInView.logo addSubview:newLogo];
```

Comment: Perfect!  My logo was a tad bit bigger so I moved it up in the newLogoView by changing CGRectMake (0,0        to     CGRectMake (0, -50     worked like a charm!  Thank you Rogare!

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a PFLoginViewController subclass so you can custom theses view controllers. If you want to change the frame you should override and set there the new frame for "loginview.logo"

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    [self.logInView.logo setFrame:CGRectMake(60.0, 12.0, 420.0, 68.0)];
}
```

I found the tutorial really helpful, I hope this work for you
https://www.parse.com/tutorials/login-and-signup-views

Comment: Great! That is the first solution which works perfect!